# Sub or Function Not Defined Error - Sub in Class Module

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to pass values from an ADODB.Recordset into a Class Module and am receiving the Sub or Function Not Defined Error when I call `Call PopulateJHAData(GeneralInfo.Range("genLoanProg"), CStr(nm))` from within the function to get the data from the recordset; I know i dont need `Call` in front of the sub; I was just seeing if it made any difference.  I can already imagine that there are a host of other items that are wrong with this code since I am just now getting into how to use Class Modules.

```
'---Class Loan Info
Public LoanNumber As String
Public InterestRate As String
Public OriginalAmount As Double
Public OriginationDate As String
Public MaturityDate As Date
Public NextPaymentDate As Date
Public PaymentAmount As Double
Public Census As String
Public RateNumber As Long
Public Margin As String
Public RoundTo As String
Public RateCeiling As String
Public RateChangeDate As Date
Public ARMNotice As String
Public QualifiedMortgageCode As String
Public ln1098 As String
Public CallReportCode As String
Public CollateralCode As String
Public PurposeCode As String
Public HPML As String
Public LoanTypeCode As String
Public Flood As String
Public CLTV As String
Public Branch As Long
Public FHLBElig As String
Public RepToCB As String
Public Occupancy As String
Public tName As String
Public eNumber As Long
Public Sub PopulateJHAData(ByVal LoanProg As String, ByVal TableName As String, ByVal JHALoanInfo As ADODB.Recordset)

        Select Case Left(LoanProg, 4)
            Case Is = "FHLB", "Cons", "15yr"
                InterestRate = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("Rate").Value)
                LoanAmount = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("OrigAmnt").Value)
                LoanDate = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("OrigDate").Value)
                MaturityDate = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("MatDate").Value)
                NextPaymentDate = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("NextPmtDate").Value)
                PaymentAmount = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("PaymentAmt").Value)
                Census = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("Census").Value)
                QualifiedMortgageCode = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("QMCode").Value)
                ln1098 = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("ln1098").Value)
                CallReportCode = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("CallRep").Value)
                CollateralCode = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("ColCode").Value)
                PurposeCode = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("PurpCode").Value)
                HPML = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("HPML").Value)
                LoanTypeCode = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("LnTypeCode").Value)
                Flood = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("Flood").Value)
                CLTV = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("CombLTV").Value)
                Branch = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("Branch").Value)
                FHLBElig = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("EligFHLV").Value)
                RepToCB = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("RepCB").Value)
                Occupancy = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("Occupancy").Value)
            Case Else
                InterestRate = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("Rate").Value)
                LoanAmount = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("OrigAmnt").Value)
                LoanDate = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("OrigDate").Value)
                MaturityDate = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("MatDate").Value)
                NextPaymentDate = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("NextPmtDate").Value)
                PaymentAmount = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("PaymentAmt").Value)
                Census = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("Census").Value)
                RateNumber = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("RateNum").Value)
                Margin = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("Margin").Value)
                RoundTo = Trim(rs.Fields("RoundTo").Value)
                RateCeiling = Trim(rs.Fields("RateCeiling").Value)
                RateChangeDate = Trim(rs.Fields("RateChangeDate").Value)
                ARMNotice = Trim(rs.Fields("ArmNot").Value)
                QualifiedMortgageCode = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("QMCode").Value)
                ln1098 = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("ln1098").Value)
                CallReportCode = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("CallRep").Value)
                CollateralCode = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("ColCode").Value)
                PurposeCode = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("PurpCode").Value)
                HPML = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("HPML").Value)
                LoanTypeCode = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("LnTypeCode").Value)
                Flood = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("Flood").Value)
                CLTV = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("CombLTV").Value)
                Branch = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("Branch").Value)
                FHLBElig = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("EligFHLV").Value)
                RepToCB = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("RepCB").Value)
                Occupancy = Trim(JHALoanInfo.Fields("Occupancy").Value)
    End Select

End Sub

Sub LoanInfoGrab()

    uName = Environ("username")
    empName = StrConv(Left(uName, Len(uName) - 1), vbProperCase)

    Dim lnNum As String
    lnNum = GeneralInfo.Range("genLoanNumber")

    msgCap = "Hello " & empName & "," & vbCrLf & _
             "The data for " & lnNum & " is not available, or unable to be retrieved." & _
             "This loan will need to be manually checked."

    Dim LoanRecordGrab As clsLoanInfo

    'passing in all potential table names/sources in array
    Set LoanRecordGrab = getLoanInfoRecord(Array(CNCTTP08, BHSCHLP8))

    Dim nm

    If LoanRecordGrab Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox msgCap, vbExclamation, "Error Getting Data"
    Else
        rem not sure if this should be the sub from the class module or if it should be LoanRecordGrab.
        'PopulateJHAData GeneralInfo.Range("genLoanProg"), CStr(nm)  yet.
    End If

    JHACheckFormat

    Dim lnData As Range, cData1 As Range, cData2 As Range
    Set lnData = JHACheck.Range("H7:H32")
    Set cData1 = JHACheck.Range("H35:H41")
    Set cData2 = JHACheck.Range("K35:K41")

    If loanData.Range("CIF_2") = vbNullString Then
        CompareJHACheck lnData, cData1
    Else
        CompareJHACheck lnData, cData1, cData2
    End If


End Sub

Function getLoanInfoRecord(arrNames) As clsLoanInfo
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String, nm, okSql As Boolean
    Dim LoanRecordGrab As clsLoanInfo


    Dim lNum As Range: Set lNum = GeneralInfo.Range("genLoanNumber")

    conn.Open CONNSTR

    'try each provided name: exit loop on successful query
    For Each nm In arrNames

        SQL = getLoanDBGrabSQL(CStr(nm), lNum)

        On Error Resume Next
        rs.Open SQL, conn 'try this name
        If Err.Number = CONNECTIONERROR Then
            okSql = False
        Else
            okSql = True
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0 'cancel on error resume next

        If okSql Then
            If rs.EOF Then
                'rs.MoveFirst
                Do While Not rs.EOF
                    Set LoanRecordGrab = New clsLoanInfo 'create an instance to populate
                    Call PopulateJHAData(GeneralInfo.Range("genLoanProg"), CStr(nm)) 'Sub or Function not Defined happens here
                    rs.MoveNext
                Loop
            End If

            Exit For 'done trying names
        End If
    Next nm

    If rs.State = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
    If conn.State = adStateOpen Then conn.Close

    Set getLoanInfoRecord = LoanRecordGrab

End Function
```

Comment: Your comment says that `PopulateJHAData` is a sub inside a class. It is not clarified later, but it looks like `LoanInfoGrab` does not belong to the same class, yet it tries to call `PopulateJHAData` without an instance of `clsLoanInfo`. You have  `Dim LoanRecordGrab As clsLoanInfo`. So call `LoanRecordGrab.PopulateJHAData`.

Comment: @GSerg doesnt `Set LoanRecordGrab = New clsLoanInfo 'create an instance to populate PopulateJHAData GeneralInfo.Range("genLoanProg"), CStr(nm), rs` call the new `clsLoanInfo` within the `Function getLoanInfoRecord(arrNames) As clsLoanInfo` ?

Comment: Why would `getLoanInfoRecord` be called by either of `Set LoanRecordGrab = New clsLoanInfo` or `PopulateJHAData GeneralInfo.Range("genLoanProg"), CStr(nm), rs`? It is not mentioned in these lines.

Comment: @GSerg I see what you are saying now.